# Inhomogeneous space between glossary items

Tags: glossaries

I did the following glossary. However, when adding it in my document, the space between items isn't always the same (see pictures).

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{drawstack}
\usepackage{nameref} % For reference
\usepackage{hyperref} % url reference
\usepackage{tikz} % State diagram
\usepackage{amsmath} % For matrix in state machine
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{lastpage} % To add lastpage référence.
\usepackage{siunitx} % For microsecond
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[toc, numberedsection,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\usepackage{chngcntr} % For table of figures section number

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\newglossaryentry{RIP}{
name=RIP,
description={Routing Information Protocol, un protocol de routage dynamique}
}
\newglossaryentry{OSPF}{
name=OSPF,
description={Open Shortless Path Finder}
}
\newglossaryentry{Hop}{
name=Hop,
description={De l'anglais, saut. Décrit le nombre de passage au travers d'un
routeur}
}
\newglossaryentry{vlsm}{
name=VLSM,
description={Variable Length Subnet Mask, sous réseau de taille variable}
}
\newglossaryentry{RFC}{
name=RFC,
description={Request for Comment, série de documents établis par l'IETF et l'ISOC
  décrivant les aspects techniques d'Internet ou de différents matériels informatiques}
}
\newglossaryentry{IETF}{
name=IETF,
description={Internet Enginnering Task Force, organisation développant des
  standards pour Internet}
}
\newglossaryentry{ISOC}{
name=ISOC,
description={Internet Society, organisation pour promouvoir et coordonner le
  développement des réseaux}
} 
\newglossaryentry{sa}{
name=SA,
description={Système autonome (Autonomous System). Ce dit d'un réseau avec
  une administration commune, comme le réseau Switch}
}
\newglossaryentry{IGP}{
name=IGP,
description={Interior Gateway Protocol, type de protocole utilisé dans un
  système autonome}
}
\newglossaryentry{EGP}{
name=EGP,
description={Exterior Gateway Protocol, type de protocole utilisé entre des
  réseaux autonomes}
}
\newglossaryentry{NDP}{
name=NDP,
description={Neighbor Discovery Protocol}
}
\newglossaryentry{ARB}{
name=ARB,
description={Area Border Router, routeur reliant deux zones différentes dans
un système autonome utlisant OSPF comme protocole de routage dynamique.}
}
\newglossaryentry{ASBR}{
name=ASBR,
description={AS Boundery Router, routeur échangeant des informations avec
  des sources en dehors du système autonome.}
}
\glsaddall
\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: That space is wanted. It's the separation of glossary entries with different first letter.

Comment: Compiling your MWE creates a blank page for me.

Comment: @Cathode Did you run `makeglossaries`?

Comment: Thank you for this explanation @TeXnician, but in small glossary like mine it is possible to get the same space every time ?

Comment: Try `\renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}` (untested) in the preamble.

Comment: @TeXnician should be `nogroupskip` as package option (at least for the predefined styles).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is rather easy. You should use the package option `nogroupskip`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[nogroupskip, toc, numberedsection,nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\newglossaryentry{RIP}{
name=RIP,
description={Routing Information Protocol, un protocol de routage dynamique}
}
\newglossaryentry{OSPF}{
name=OSPF,
description={Open Shortless Path Finder}
}
\newglossaryentry{Hop}{
name=Hop,
description={De l'anglais, saut. Décrit le nombre de passage au travers d'un
routeur}
}
\newglossaryentry{vlsm}{
name=VLSM,
description={Variable Length Subnet Mask, sous réseau de taille variable}
}
\newglossaryentry{RFC}{
name=RFC,
description={Request for Comment, série de documents établis par l'IETF et l'ISOC
  décrivant les aspects techniques d'Internet ou de différents matériels informatiques}
}
\newglossaryentry{IETF}{
name=IETF,
description={Internet Enginnering Task Force, organisation développant des
  standards pour Internet}
}
\newglossaryentry{ISOC}{
name=ISOC,
description={Internet Society, organisation pour promouvoir et coordonner le
  développement des réseaux}
} 
\newglossaryentry{sa}{
name=SA,
description={Système autonome (Autonomous System). Ce dit d'un réseau avec
  une administration commune, comme le réseau Switch}
}
\newglossaryentry{IGP}{
name=IGP,
description={Interior Gateway Protocol, type de protocole utilisé dans un
  système autonome}
}
\newglossaryentry{EGP}{
name=EGP,
description={Exterior Gateway Protocol, type de protocole utilisé entre des
  réseaux autonomes}
}
\newglossaryentry{NDP}{
name=NDP,
description={Neighbor Discovery Protocol}
}
\newglossaryentry{ARB}{
name=ARB,
description={Area Border Router, routeur reliant deux zones différentes dans
un système autonome utlisant OSPF comme protocole de routage dynamique.}
}
\newglossaryentry{ASBR}{
name=ASBR,
description={AS Boundery Router, routeur échangeant des informations avec
  des sources en dehors du système autonome.}
}
\glsaddall
\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

[image: results]

Comment: Perfect, thank you. @TeXnician answer work as well.

Comment: @Nakrule If it works it's fine. But this answer is the documented method from the package documentation.