# Uneven spacing between glossary entrances in the list

Tags: spacing, glossaries, acronyms, glossaries-extra

I am trying to make a glossary list and there is something weird going on: the spacing between entrances is uneven for no obvious reason. The minimal example of the code is below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nonumberlist,acronym]{glossaries-extra}

\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{6.5in}

\newglossarystyle{acronyms}{%acronymsandsymbols
    \setglossarystyle{long}% based on the list style
    \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1}
    \renewcommand*{\glossarypreamble}{\vspace{4ex}
    \glsresetentrycounter} %
}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{ASR}{ASR}{angular spectrum decomposition    (representation)}
\newacronym{TAM}{TAM}{total angular momentum (TAM) vector}
\newacronym{OAM}{OAM}{orbital angular momentum}
\newacronym{SAM}{SAM}{spin angular momentum}
\newacronym{QM}{QM}{quantum qechanics}
\newacronym{QFT}{QFT}{quantum field theory}
\newacronym{QED}{QED}{quantum electrodynamics}

\begin{document}
\printglossary[style=acronyms,type=\acronymtype]
\newpage

Hello here

\glsaddall

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As you can see from your example, the spacing is smaller for entries that share the same first letter and larger between entries with different first letters. This can be turned off using teh `nogroupskip` class option.

Comment: Possible dupliate of [Inhomogeneous space between glossary items](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/359226/134144)? Also closely related: [How do I remove alphabetical grouping of acronyms in the list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/129294/134144)  and [glossary with undesired space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339676/134144)